# how to call columns from different table using sub-queries in mysql with certain condition

Tags: mysql, subquery, where-clause

//this is the question
Find customer name, order number and order amount if order amount is greater than average
sales amount of the customers and sort the record by customer name [Hint: use WHERE
clause].

```
SELECT 
name, orderno, amount
FROM
customerinfo,
orderdetails
WHERE
amount > (SELECT 
        AVG(amount)
    FROM
        orderdetails)

ORDER BY name;
```

//this the result [the result are not what i look for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wBs6.png)

this the table coding

```
CREATE TABLE customerinfo (
customercode VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR(60),
poscode INT(5),
city VARCHAR(30),
state VARCHAR(30),
hpno VARCHAR(20),
email VARCHAR(50),
salesmanid VARCHAR(10),
PRIMARY KEY (customercode),
FOREIGN KEY (salesmanid)
    REFERENCES salesman (salesmanid)
);

CREATE TABLE salesman (
salesmanid VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
salesmanname VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (salesmaniD)
);

CREATE TABLE orderinfo (
orderno INT(10) NOT NULL,
ordertype VARCHAR(50),
orderdate DATE,
deliverydate DATE,
PRIMARY KEY (orderno)
);

CREATE TABLE orderdetails (
orderno INT(10) NOT NULL,
itemcode VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
quantity INT(5),
amount DECIMAL(9 , 2 ),
PRIMARY KEY (orderno , itemcode),
FOREIGN KEY (orderno)
    REFERENCES orderinfo (orderno),
FOREIGN KEY (itemcode)
    REFERENCES item (itemcode)
);

CREATE TABLE item (
itemcode VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
itemdesc VARCHAR(60),
unit VARCHAR(10),
sellingprice DECIMAL(9 , 2 ) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (itemcode)
);

CREATE TABLE ordersalesmaninfo (
salesmanid VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
orderno INT(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (salesmanid),
FOREIGN KEY (salesmanid)
    REFERENCES salesman(salesmanid),
FOREIGN KEY (orderno)
    REFERENCES orderinfo (orderno)
);
```

i may have problem with the normalisation process but i think there will not cause any impact to the question .

Comment: I do not think that you have entered in your database any relation between the customer and the order.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output (no images). Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)